# Connecting to clients server - Safe?

Tags: webmasters

I just started working with a new client who is overseas (as many of my clients are) and I'll be doing work on their website.

They gave me their login information along with their FTP information so that I can access their server via my Mac. Normally I only have server access when working on-site, so connecting to someones FTP is something I've never done with my personal computer.

My question is - If I connect to their server, will they be able to see any of my files, use any of my files, or have any access to my computer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on one of the Technology stackexchange sites, not here.  http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is - If I connect to their server will they be able to see
>   any of my files, use any of my files, or have any access to my
>   computer?

**Answer is No**. Either you connect to the client's FTP server from your personal computer, or you access client PC remotely using software like TeamViewer. The client will not have any access to your computer. This will be just like having 1-way communication, not 2-way. So feel free to work from your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was worried that anything I did while connected to their FTP would put my work on their server.

Comment: No no , do not worry. enjoy your work.. One more suggestion I would like to give that take back of files of that ftp before you change any file so in future you can use backup to upload if any issue comes.